# collision detection error:AttributeError: type object 'Ship_laser' has no attribute 'sprites'

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to write a game using a model, but i get the error:

```
 "File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1514, in spritecollide
    for s in group.sprites():AttributeError: type object 'Ship_laser' has no attribute 'sprites'"
```

when running the script.If i dont call my collision function the script runs, so in that function is the mistake,but i dont understand where's the mistake.Here is the code of the function:

```
def collisions():
for enemy_ship in classes.Enemy_ship.List:
    enemy_laser = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy_ship, classes.Ship_laser, True)
    if len(enemy_laser) > 0:
        for hit in enemy_laser:
            enemy_ship.health -= 25




for laser in classes.Ship_laser.List:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(laser, enemy_ship, True):
        laser.destroy()
```

If it's needed i am posting the the Ship_laser class from my classes.py file

```
class Ship_laser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

def __init__(self, x, y,  image_string):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    Ship_laser.allsprites.add(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
    self.velx, self.vely = 0, 0

@staticmethod
def laser_movement(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT):
    for laser in Ship_laser.List:
        laser.rect.x += laser.velx
        laser.rect.y += laser.vely

def destroy(self):
    Ship_laser.List.remove(self)

    del self
```

Considering that the Laser.ship class it's inheriting the pygame.sprite.Sprite class i dont understand the error.This is my first game.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I am an expert with pygame, nor do I fully understand how you have built your classes. When I hear ship laser, I think of a single instance that belongs to a ship, yet in your class you define "allsprites" which is mutable type defined to a class instance (shared by all members of the class).

But given this, allsprites will be the same mutable object shared among ever ship_laser, almost like the yellowpages of your class. When you call pygame.sprite.spritecollide (based on pygame docs) it is looking for the sprite.Group and hence, you should pass it the group lookup (the yellowpages aka allsprites) rather than the reference to the class. That should sort your issues. So, here is your code change:

```
enemy_laser = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy_ship, classes.Ship_laser, True)
```

to

```
enemy_laser = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy_ship, classes.Ship_laser.allsprites, True)
```